# Are there any valid, and person readable, checksums possible?

Tags: md5

We've been trying to produce a valid, and pretty, MD5. Something that has repeating digits, or spells a word, or something. It's probably more difficult than spelling out the dictionary on a calculator whilst standing on your head on top of a washing machine on ship in the arctic but it's always made me curious.

Are there any valid, and person readable, checksums possible? Or would the checksum itself typically prevent this?

I'm preparing for some massive flames to blow my way.

Comment: readable $\mapsto$ memorizable $\:$ ? $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: You are conflating your requirements. Readability can be handled by an *encoding* of arbitrary data, e.g., [Bubble Babble](http://wiki.yak.net/589/Bubble_Babble_Encoding.txt).

Comment: Whatever your criteria for 'pretty' are, finding a message with a given MD5 is a pre-image attack; and as far as I know this is not practical.

Comment: I think OP is looking for something similar to the [PGP word list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGP_word_list).

Comment: actually I think he is looking to see if there is a plaintext that would create a hash like 0xABBAABBAABBAABBAABBAABBAABBAABBA

Comment: For the flame: You should not use MD5 at all, it is broken. Use a newer Hash function like SHA-2 or SHA-3 instead (maybe suitably truncated before encoding in a readable way).

Answer (score 3):

You could use a concept similar to the [PGP Word List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGP_word_list), which attempts to make a binary-representative equivalent of the NATO Phonetic Alphabet, so that fingerprints (bytes) can be expressed vocally in a relatively unambiguous way.

Of course, using per-byte words in the case of MD5 means you need 16 words to produce a readable checksum, which may be potentially excessive for your purposes. If this is the case, your options are to either truncate the hash (which is potentially not ideal from a security perspective) or to invent additional words codepoints to shorten the total string length. Unfortunately the required dictionary size raises geometrically ($2^n$) whereas the length only reduces linearly, which means you need much larger dictionaries to get slightly shorter strings. You'll have to work out a balance point.